# Excel, getStringCellValue returns float

Tags: java, excel, cell

i am getting string from excel cell. In my cell there is an integer. But this code brings a float. For example in my cell there is a number 409 but it brings 409.0 how to fix this? i need to bring exact 409?

```
 public String getCell(int x, int y) {

        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y);
        if (cell.getCellType()
                == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            return "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
        }
        return "" + cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.round() will round the number and return an int